# How do I need to declare a member class?

Tags: c++, header

I need to use a custom exception class that's goign to be used from within member the function of the top-level class. So, it's reasonble to put the custom class as a member class. Here is the file where they're declared presently:

`conductor.h`:

```
class conductor
{
    //some staff
private:
    class bad_index : public std::exception
    {
    public:
        bad_index(int);
        virtual const char* what() const noexcept;
    private:
        int _idx;
    };
};
```

I'm new to programming in C++ and still haven't learn how the C++ programmer're used to doing such things? Maybe we should put class `bad_index` as an incomplete type like that:

```
class conductor
{
    //some staff
private:
    class bad_index;
};
```

and make it complete and implement all member-functions in the `cpp`-file. What is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as `bad_index` is private, it can't be referenced outside the class, so it can't be used in exception handlers other than `catch(...)`. If it's not really needed (that is, the exception is made only for internal use), perhaps it's enough to not make it a nested class but to define `bad_index` in the implementation file in `namespace { ... }`.

In case that `bad_index` is actually public, technically you can declare it in .h file and define in .cpp file, but it will again be unusable in `catch` clauses of class users, because you can't catch an exception of incomplete type even by reference, all you can do to catch it is again `catch(...)`.

Comment: So, you;d propose to declare them in the same namespace isntead?

Answer (score 1):

If the class is not part of public interface of your top level class then it makes sense to put al little information about it into the header file as possible and forward declaration does that job well. However if all the code that uses that exception is in one cpp file then you could as well avoid mentioning it in the header at all and declare in an anonymous namespace inside the cpp file.